# How do you parse an HTML string for image tags to get at the SRC information?

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex, xpath

Currently I use .Net `WebBrowser.Document.Images()` to do this. It requires the `Webrowser` to load the document. It's messy and takes up resources.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php) XPath is better than a regex at this.

Anyone know how to do this in C#?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If your input string is valid XHTML you can treat is as xml, load it into an xmldocument, and do XPath magic :) But it's not always the case.

Otherwise you can try this function, that will return all image links from HtmlSource :

```
public List<Uri> FetchLinksFromSource(string htmlSource)
{
    List<Uri> links = new List<Uri>();
    string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
    MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
    {
        string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
        links.Add(new Uri(href));
    }
    return links;
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        List<Uri> links = FetchLinksFromSource(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was banging my head over my own regex!

Comment: `([^'"" >]+?)` doesn't work if href includes spaces!

Comment: The `using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream() )` line is missing an additional closing bracket.

Answer (score 11):

The big issue with any HTML parsing is the "well formed" part. You've seen the crap HTML out there - how much of it is really well formed? I needed to do something similar - parse out all links in a document (and in my case) update them with a rewritten link. I found the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) over on CodePlex. It rocks (and handles malformed HTML).

Here's a snippet for iterating over links in a document:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Sample.HTM");
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/@href");

Content match = null;

// Run only if there are links in the document.
if (linkNodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
    {
        HtmlAttribute attrib = linkNode.Attributes["href"];
        // Do whatever else you need here
    }
}
```

[Original Blog Post](http://www.rcs-solutions.com/blog/2008/08/13/ProcessingHTMLDocuments.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is images I would just use a regular expression. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"<img.*?src=""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score -3):

If it's valid xhtml, you could do this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(html);
XmlNodeList results = doc.SelectNodes("//img/@src");
```

Comment: Good luck loading 90% of the html pages out there into an XmlDocument :)

Comment: Already tried this. HTML is not valid XML. And thus throws an exception.

Comment: @RobertoBonini you're an expert!