# How to remove first image from string

Tags: php

I have the results from a database that contains images and text. I would like to remove the first image.

Example:

```
$string = 'This is some text and images 
    <img src="http://linktoimage" border="0">,
    more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on';
```

I would like to remove the first image, it is not always the same url.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Because your string is in fact regular, you may accomplish this with a simple regular expression. Please try it, and post what you've written so far if/when you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
$string = 'This is some text and images 
    <img src="http://linktoimage" border="0">,
    more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on';

print preg_replace('/<img(.*)>/i','',$string,1);
```

The above should return

```
This is some text and images 
,
    more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on
```

Assuming you know it'll be prefixed by spaces and a line break, and suffixed by a comma and line break (and you want to remove these, too), you can do

```php
print preg_replace("/\n    <img(.*)>\,\n    /i",'',$string,1);
```

Which will give you

```
This is some text and images more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on
```

Comment: Yep, this one, except you should probably have: preg_replace('/<img(.*)>/i','',$string,1)

Comment: @Slavic Making it case-insensitive won't hurt, indeed. I added it, thank you.

Comment: I meant the otehr thing though :) You had too much text around the needed text (<img...) but you edited it out by the time I submited my comment :)

Comment: @Slavic As long as it's better. :)

Comment: After thinking a little, this doesn't quite work for cases when ther eare new line characters in the tag. How do we fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There was a great answer on another [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196570/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-the-first-image-source-from-html-codes)

```
function get_first_image($html){
    require_once('SimpleHTML.class.php')

    $post_dom = str_get_dom($html);

    $first_img = $post_dom->find('img', 0);

    if($first_img !== null) {
        return $first_img->src;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can do it via Regex expressions however regex isn't really suited for this.

Comment: On the contrary, I think html parsers are overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: I agree with Slavic, I think regex is perfectly suitable for this. [No, HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but for something like this I think it's a lot more suitable than loading a huge HTML parser.

Comment: The problem with it is getting the correct regex string, remember that its not always https://XXX/img.jpg, you could also end up parsing images which are not images for example <!-- img src="blah" --> it may be overkill but if you cannot validate or scrub the input it may be the best way ;)

Comment: Nope. Your string won't match the regex. (<!-- img src="blah" -->)

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 'This is some text and images 
       <img src="http://linktoimage" border="0">, 
       more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on';

echo preg_replace('/<img.*?>/', '123', $var, 1);
```

This should do it. ? in the regex is to make it ungreedy.

Answer (score 0):

Being a RegEx newbie, I tend to avoid it and use something like:

```
$i = strpos($string,'<img');
if ($i !== false) {
    $j = strpos($string, '>', $i);
    if ($j !== false) $string = substr($string,0,$i) . substr($string,$j);
}
```

Probably should be `$i-1` and/or `$j+1` - I never remember exactly what it should be.

Comment: shed the fear, embrace the regex - you'll be happier in the end.

Comment: I know @KevinDTimm! Is there a RegEx Support Group out there for me, with, like, cookies and folding chairs? :-)

Comment: Sorry, your code won't work if there are any other tags in the beginning. The condition ws to remove first img tag. And it's not the only downside.

Answer (score 0):

Finally nailed it down:

```
preg_replace('/<img[\S\s]*?>/i','',$txt,1)
```

This one also works for cases when you might have:

```
$string = 'This is some text and images 
    <img 
        src="http://linktoimage" border="0">,
    more text and <img src="http://linktoanotherimage"> and so on';
```

(a new line character in the tag.)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

$html is your html content variable from which you want to remove first image tag.

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>)/i','',$html,1);
```