# How to find all img tags on a string?

Tags: c#

I want to find all img tags in a string of text and put a surrounding link - a tag around it.
What's the best way to do it? And I want to retrieve the src link and put in the href attribute.

By the way I'm doing it in C# but the way should be similar in every language. Has anybody done such filtering and replacing? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're parsing and dealing with raw HTML strings, I would highly recommend using the [Html Agility Pack library](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Answer (score 2):

[How do you parse an HTML string for image tags to get at the SRC information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138839/how-do-you-parse-a-html-string-for-image-tags-to-get-at-the-src-information)