# RegEx for extracting HTML Image properties

Tags: .net, html, regex, html-content-extraction

I need a RegEx pattern for extracting all the properties of an image tag.

As we all know, there are lots of malformed HTML out there, so the pattern has to cover those possibilities.

I was looking at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php but it didn't quite get it all:

I come up something like:

```
(alt|title|src|height|width)\s*=\s*["'][\W\w]+?["']
```

Is there any possibilities I'll be missing or a more efficient simple pattern?

EDIT:

Sorry, I will be more specific, I'm doing this using .NET so it's on the server side.

I've already a list of img tags, now I just need to parse the properties.

Comment: Ack. And again "it depends" is the answer. You can use regex if you know beforehand what *exactly* you will be working on, you should use a parser if you can't guarantee well-formedness.

Comment: [Beware of Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078)

Answer (score 5):

> As we all know, there are lots of malformed HTML out there, so the pattern has to cover those possibilities.

It won't. Use a HTML parser if you have to parse "evil" (from an unknown source) HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a big concern I'd go with an html parser (like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in python) if you are doing this server-side or [jquery](http://jquery.com) or just plain javascript if you are doing it client-side. Granted it is overkill but it is a lot quicker, less likely to have bugs (since they've thought of the corner cases), and it will handle the potential malformedness.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead of using regex.  It's designed to handle a lot of cases and can save you more than a few headaches due to hammering out edge cases

Answer (score 0):

If you want **all** attribute values, might I suggest using the DOM? Something like `element.attributes` will work well.

If you insist on a regex `//\b\w+="[^"]+"//` should get everything.

Answer (score 0):

Before comitting yourself to regex, see what it can do: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

```
/<img(\s+([a-z]{3,})=(["']([^"']*)["']|[\S]))+\s*/?>/i
```

A match_all on this, will return (format depends on your library, but key indexes are):

```
0 -> image tag
1 -> attribute
2 -> attribute name
3 -> attribute value (with enclosing quotes if exists)
4 -> attribute value (without enclosing quotes if it has them, otherwise empty, use 3)
```