# Get all images url from string

Tags: php, html, string, image, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Hi,
I have found solution to get first image from string:

```
preg_match('~<img[^>]*src\s?=\s?[\'"]([^\'"]*)~i',$string, $matches);
```

But I can't manage to get all images from string.
One more thing... If image contains alternative text (`alt` attribute) how to get it too and save to another variable?
Thanks in advance,
Ilija

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php/138614#138614

Comment: `[^&gt;]` does not work as I suspect you think :) It actually says "anything which is not either &, g, t or ;", NOT "anything but the string &gt;". That said: parse using DOM instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I tried but can't get it print value of src

```
 $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the table by its tag name ***/
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    /*** loop over the table rows ***/
    foreach ($images as $img)
    {
        /*** get each column by tag name ***/
        $url = $img->getElementsByTagName('src');
        /*** echo the values ***/
        echo $url->nodeValue;
        echo '<hr />';
    }
```

**EDIT: I solved this problem**

```
$dom = new domDocument;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($string);

/*** discard white space ***/
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($images as $img)
    {
        $url = $img->getAttribute('src');   
        $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');   
        echo "Title: $alt<br>$url<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 33):

Don't do this with regular expressions. Instead, parse the HTML. Take a look at [Parse HTML With PHP And DOM](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html). This is a standard feature in PHP 5.2.x (and probably earlier). Basically the logic for getting images is roughly:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

This should be trivial to adapt to finding images.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the best solution.

Comment: Hi cletus,
This looks very simple and much better solution than regular expressions. Still, I didn't manage to make it work with images. Is there any other link with some better explanation?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: I love you. I know totally constructive comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Regular Expressions are a bad approach to parsing anything that involves matching braces.

You'd be better off using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) class.

Comment: Heh, Cletus beat me to it of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You assume that you can parse HTML using regular expressions. That may work for some sites, but not all sites. Since you are limiting yourself to only a subset of all web pages, it would be interesting to know how you limit yourself... maybe you can parse the HTML in a quite easy way from php.

Answer (score 0):

Look at preg_match_all to get all matches.