# Matching SRC attribute of IMG tag using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match, src

I'm attempting to run preg_match to extract the SRC attribute from the first IMG tag in an article (in this case, stored in $row->introtext).

```
preg_match('/\< *[img][^\>]*[src] *= *[\"\']{0,1}([^\"\']*)/i', $row->introtext, $matches);
```

Instead of getting something like

```
images/stories/otakuzoku1.jpg
```

from

```
<img src="images/stories/otakuzoku1.jpg" border="0" alt="Inside Otakuzoku's store" />
```

I get just

```
0
```

The regex should be right, but I can't tell why it appears to be matching the border attribute and not the src attribute.

Alternatively, if you've had the patience to read this far without skipping straight to the reply field and typing 'use a HTML/XML parser', can a good tutorial for one be recommended as I'm having trouble finding one at all that's applicable to PHP 4.

PHP 4.4.7

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your expression is incorrect. Try:

```
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $row->introtext, $matches);
```

Note the removal of brackets around img and src and some other cleanups.

Comment: This did the trick. Not the 'ideal' solution of actually parsing the HTML, but the one solution that works and gives the neccessary result. Thanks!

Comment: as a side note, $matches[0] contains the full IMG tag, and $matches[1] contains the source URI.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it with built-in functions (php >= 4):

```
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $html, $values);
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    if ($val['tag'] == 'IMG') {
        $first_src = $val['attributes']['SRC'];
        break;
    }
}

echo $first_src;  // images/stories/otakuzoku1.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use `preg_match()` itself, try this:

```
 preg_match('/(?<!_)src=([\'"])?(.*?)\\1/',$content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
include ("htmlparser.inc"); // from: http://php-html.sourceforge.net/

$html = 'bla <img src="images/stories/otakuzoku1.jpg" border="0" alt="Inside Otakuzoku\'s store" /> noise <img src="das" /> foo';

$parser = new HtmlParser($html);

while($parser->parse()) {
    if($parser->iNodeName == 'img') {
        echo $parser->iNodeAttributes['src'];
        break;
    }
}
```

which will produce:

```
images/stories/otakuzoku1.jpg
```

It should work with PHP 4.x.

Comment: Some problems getting htmlparser.inc to work. Error message says the class is already initiated, but it isn't. I'll hold out for a provider upgrade to PHP 5...

Comment: Have you tried `include_once('htmlparser.inc');` instead of `include('htmlparser.inc');`?

Answer (score 1):

The regex I used was much simpler.  My code assumes that the string being passed to it contains exactly one img tag with no other markup:

```
$pattern = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
```

See my answer here for more info: [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php/3815188#3815188)

Comment: "exactly one img tag with no other markup"? That's a pretty specific case isn't it, maybe a bit too specific for almost everyone :[

Answer (score 1):

This task should be executed by a dom parser because regex is dom-ignorant.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/narqY))

```
$row = (object)['introtext' => '<div>test</div><img src="source1"><p>text</p><img src="source2"><br>'];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($row->introtext);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Output:

```
source1
```

This says:

1. Parse the whole html string
2. Isolate all of the img tags
3. Isolate the first img tag
4. Isolate its src attribute value

Clean, appropriate, easy to read and manage.