# Simple PHP DOM Parser doesn't work in switch case (PHP)

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have a problem with the Simple PHP DOM Parser. I basically have to scrape a catalogue site for the images and their titles.

The site is have to scrape is http://pinesite.com.

I have come up with the following code to do it (this will be called via AJAX):

```
<?php
include ('simple_html_dom.php');
$function = $_GET['function'];
switch($function) {
  case 'subcat':
    $maincat = $_GET['cat'];
    $url = "http://www.pinesite.com/meubelen/index.php?".$maincat."&lang=de";
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $data = $html->find('.box_166_content .act_path li a');
    $output ="";
    foreach ($data as $subcat) {
      $title = $subcat->plaintext;
      $href = $subcat->href;
      $link['title'] = $title;
      $link['href'] =substr($href,10);
      $output[] = $link;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);
    unset($url);
    break;

  case 'images':
    $subcat = $_GET['subcat'];
    $url = "http://www.pinesite.com/meubelen/index.php?".$subcat;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $iframe = $html->find('#the_iframe',0);
    $url2 = $iframe->src;
    $html->clear(); 
    unset($html);

    $html2 = file_get_html("http://www.pinesite.com/meubelen/".$url2);
    $titles = $html2->find('p');
    $images = $html2->find('img');
    $output='';
    $i=0;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
      $item['title'] = $titles[$i]->plaintext;
      $item['thumb'] = $image->src;
      $item['image'] = str_replace('thumb_','',$image->src);
      $output[] = $item;
      $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    break;
}
?>
```

So that's the "functions" file, the part that doesn't work is the last case.

I don't know what wrong here, so I tested it (the last case) in a separate file (I put the URL that it gets from the iFrame (that part does work):

```
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";

$fullurl = "http://www.pinesite.com/meubelen/prog/browse.php?taal=nl&groep=18&subgroep=26";

$html = file_get_html($fullurl);
$titles = $html->find('p');
$images = $html->find('img');
$output='';
$i=0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $item['title'] = $titles[$i]->plaintext;
  $item['thumb'] = $image->src;
  $item['image'] = str_replace('thumb_','',$image->src);
  $output[] =$item;
  $i++;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Like I said the first part should return the same as the second (if you add ?function=images&subcat=dichte-kast) but it doesn't. I'm guessing it is because I use the parser multiple times.

Does anybody have a suggestion for me?

Comment: Nowhere have you actually checked if the url retrieval worked. Does `$url2` actually have a valid url in it? does `$html2` have some page contents? Your script utterly depends on the server's network connection being stable and the remote site being available, with no margin for ANY error.

Comment: I know :), this is just a test of the scraping, I will fix all that before it goes live.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that your `$url2` variable contains html entities and when you concat it to the root url the result is not a valid url. Therefore, the `file_get_html()` function will not retrieve the url (and thus the data) you expect, but something different.

A quick solution to your problem is [html_entity_decode()](http://nl2.php.net/html_entity_decode), but you might want to read up on debugging too. It can be as easy as applying `var_dump();` to every variable you're using and see where the output is different from the output you expect.

You might also want to check on some security issues, too. Writing `$subcat = $_GET['sub_cat']` is in no way safer than using `$_GET['sub_cat']` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something like, and yes, I know about the whole security issue. I will fix these once I actually have a basic working version.

Comment: Be so kind to approve my answer if it has helped you :).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand the question completely but from what I can gather is that you are trying to grab some images and their associated titles from a given webpage and then save them?  If thats the case then here is some food for thought.  (sorry it could not be more specific).

use file_get_contents to grab the html contents.

```
$html = file_get_contents('www.someurl.com');
```

then preg_match() all of the image tags and other data you may need. There is lots of info out there on how to do this [Matching SRC attribute of IMG tag using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180255/matching-src-attribute-of-img-tag-using-preg-match)

```
 $matches = preg_match('<img>*<\/img>', $html); # this is a guess
```

Once you have a collection of image tags as an array then use curl to save the images

```
http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/
```

I think the problem you have is stripping the html content fromt he content that you want

Comment: He's already using a DOM parser to do this. Besides, his problem is not in his parsing method.

Comment: ahh, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Just check out http://pinesite, click on a category and then a sub category on the left. All that I want to do is get the src of the product images plus their titles in a JSON format so that I can use them.