# how to sub-string from string by specifying the start and end characters?

Tags: php, explode, split

I have some texts that are always begin with an image tag , so i want to print the text without the image by specifying the start and the end characters of the string that should be removed and get the rest of the text, something like:

```
explode($text, '<img', '/>'); // where explode($string, $start_chars, $end_chars);
```

for example:

`$text = "<img src='anything' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Hello World!</h1>";`

the output should be `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`

so how I can do that in php?

Comment: please show example text and desired output

Comment: Can do it the hard way with string functions. I would advise regular expression. Discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180255/matching-src-attribute-of-img-tag-using-preg-match

Comment: @Twisty I hope that there is a better solution, thanks

Comment: all you need for your example is: `strip_tags($text)`

Comment: @Dagon strip_tags() will remove all the tags, I want to remove only the first img tag

Comment: there only is one. it does exactly what you ask based on your example

Comment: @Dagon the text after the img contain a lot of html tags, I just wrote a small example

Comment: don't make it hard to answer you, your asking for free help. I'm stopping my paid work to assist you - but i'm going back to it now.

Comment: @Dagon lol, I appreciate that, thank you, but I didn't the suitable answer tell yet

Comment: Your questions was not clear. It come off as wanting the text in the source. Not just popping off the IMG tag from a much larger string of HTML. Please give a better example of what is being worked with.

Comment: simply, I have a large html text started with an img tag, i want to remove the img tag from the text only !

Comment: but in your example `<h1>` must be removed too?

Comment: @Leggendario, no just the first img tag should be removed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be the optimal answer:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($m->en);
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
$string = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Revised based on new question...

Use DOMDocument:

```
$text = "<img src='anything' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Hello World!</h1>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$h1Tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');
$string = $dom->saveHTML($h1Tags->item(0));
echo $string;
```

Output: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for more info / examples

Comment: I tried them all, no one gave the required result

Comment: You changed the question somewhat, from when I started typing. Take a look at the new answer

Comment: OMG you changed it again!! I give up.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$text = "<img src='anything' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Hello World!</h1>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

$dom->removeChild($dom->doctype);           
$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given some text like:

```
<img src='img1.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 1</h1>
<img src='img2.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 2</h1>
<img src='img4.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 3</h1>
```

You state you want to collect just the text that would appear between the IMG tags. This was not clear upfront, and was suggested, you can use the DOMDocument to parse the HTML.

Using Regular Expressions is another way to go. Example: https://regex101.com/r/kH0xA3/1

```
$re = "/<*img.*\\/>(.*)/im"; 
$str = "<img src='img1.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 1</h1>\n<img src='img2.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 2</h1>\n<img src='img4.png' width='100' height='200'/><h1>Title 3</h1>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score -2):

You may have not heard of the substr() function of PHP. It is indicated in here!

http://php.net/substr

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: the substr() function work by specifying the index of characters in the string, not specifying substrings as i need in my case !!

Comment: Also does not do everything that would be needed, `strpos()` to help find parts to sub out.