# PHP reqular expression: extracting title of img tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to learn reg exp,

i want to get title of `<img` only from the text

the text is differ and basically look like this

```
<a href="http://abcde.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://abcde.com/img/aa.jpg" title="img title" id="img id" class="img class" />
```

any guidance and advise are appreciated..

Comment: `expression` not `expersion` in the subject.... please :( - or `regex` to save some typing and spelling pitfalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in this so answer:

[How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

a lot of good answers !

Answer (score 3):

it would be something like that:

```
'|<img(.*)title="(.*)"(.*)/>|Um'
```

but i would advise to parse html through dom ([DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), etc):

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$imgElement = $doc->getElementById('img id');
$title = $imgElement->getAttribute('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the answer "Don't use regular expressions!" But if you still want to, try:

```
#<img[^>]+title="([^"]*)"#
```

PS: This regex assumes that there is no `>` in any attribute before `title`. If this may not be assumed, say so.