# How can i get src alone from Image tag using php?

Tags: php, html, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

```
<img width="200" height="300" src="http://runapvo.apivo.com/files/2011/06/2444-200x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="2444" title="2444" />
```

From this image tag I need to take `src` alone. How can I do this? Is there any predefined functions available?...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+src+html+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it into a DOM tree with `loadHtml` and do an xpath on it, or directly traverse it if the structure is always the same.

See [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php/138614#138614)

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming that you are displaying the image on your page

You should use an [html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). This will allow you to parse your own page. Although I am tempted to ask why you would want to do this in php of all languages? If you simply need the src on a static page, that shouldn't change so there is no need to call php everytime you want to get its src. If it is dynamic (as in defined by a php variable) you should still be able to access that variable.

### Assuming the page does not belong to you

You are going to want to scrape the page using regex and php, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php) pretty much answers how.

#### Side Note:

If it is not necessary to do it in php I would suggest passing the work onto the client using the following *javascript* function:

```
document.getElementById("MyIMG").src
```

The only reason this might not be favorable is if the server needs that src, the client won't have js (ie a phone browser), or the client is so bad running extra javascript might crash it :)