# Get height and Width attribute with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

```
<img src="......" width="....." height="...."/>
```

If I have a function generating the above code, how can I get the width and height attributes with php?

Comment: Ca you please elaborate question with suitable example?

Comment: Why is this tagged wordpress, is it a wordpress function generating the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php/143455#143455) ?

So you would need to use

```
preg_match_all('/(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
```

And then foreach them to array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getimagesize()`

```
<?php    
     list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://example.com/image.gif");
?>
<img src="..." width="<?= $width ?> height="<?= $height ?>" />
```