# Regex pattern for preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

I want to allow users upload images to uploads/tmp folder for future use in their posts.
1. User uploads several images to 'uploads/tmp/'
Here is his text:

```
Some text with img tags:
    1. <img src="http://site.com/uploads/tmp/d272b2d4.jpg">
    2. <img src="http://www.site.com/uploads/tmp/132784ca.jpg">
    3. <img src="www.site.com/uploads/tmp/e08b0bc8.jpg">
    4. <img src="site.com/uploads/tmp/f40ba84c.jpg">
```

I want to get those filenames from src property and move files to desired folder and then to replace images to:

```
1. <img src="http://site.com/uploads/posts/user/d272b2d4.jpg">
2. <img src="http://www.site.com/uploads/posts/user/132784ca.jpg">
3. <img src="www.site.com/uploads/tmp/posts/user/e08b0bc8.jpg">
4. <img src="site.com/uploads/tmp/posts/user/f40ba84c.jpg">
```

So the problem is I can't create the pattern for getting and replacing filenames in src and would be grateful for any help. I'm using PHP.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this, I would use something like DOM Document. There is too much room for error using regex to parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
preg_match_all( '/(?:src=\")((?:http(?:s|):\/\/|)(?:www\.|)site\.com\/uploads\/tmp\/[a-z0-9]+\.jpg(?:\")/is', $subject, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get all the sources if you are passing more then one `img` tags to it in the `$subject`.

```
preg_match_all( '/(?:src=\")(.+)(?:\")/i', $subject, $matches);
```

Test `$matches` for matches

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: I need to apply it only for img from my host..

Comment: How is the `img` going to be passed to PHP for the match? A string with one `img` in it or a bunch of `img` tags?

Comment: it could be the full story about travel with photos