# Extract part of string with PHP

Tags: php, string, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

This would be an example of string:

```
$src = '<img src="/avatars/admin.jpg" class="avatar 23 avatar-30 avatar-default" height="30" width="30" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="avatar">';
```

---

**`$out` should be `/avatars/admin.jpg`**

Problem is that `/avatars/admin.jpg` is path to avatar of current logged user, so it's dynamically changed.

How to get `$out` in simplest way?

Comment: I'm PHP noob, I have only idea how to do this with jQuery .attr() , but that is bad solution. I would be thankful just for guideline, place to start.

Comment: @enloz you can do as mentioned by alex. The same question was asked before
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if this is the only HTML you need to process, you could probably get away with a regex...

```
preg_match('/\ssrc="([^"]+)"/', $src, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php
and http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php

you could use a combination of both, such as substr( $string, strpos('src="') + 5, strpos('.jpg') + 4 );

i didnt try it, cuz i dont really know what u r trying to "extract" , but now u get the basic idea ;)

g.r.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can set the string to be:

`$str = '<img src="/avatars/$avatar.jpg" class="avatar 23 avatar-30 avatar-default" height="30" width="30" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="avatar">';`

Otherwise, I'd use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "$src = '<img src="/avatars/admin.jpg" class="avatar 23 avatar-30 avatar-default" height="30" width="30" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="avatar">';
";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "<img src=", " class=");

echo $parsed; //
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
$src = '<img src="/avatars/admin.jpg" class="avatar 23 avatar-30 avatar-default" height="30" width="30" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="avatar">';
$regex = '|src="(.+?)"|';
preg_match($regex,$src,$match);
$out = $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$src = '<img src="/avatars/admin.jpg" class="avatar 23 avatar-30 avatar-default" \
height="30" width="30" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" alt="avatar">';

$start = strpos($src, '"') + 1;
$end = $start + strpos($src, '"', $start - 1) - 1;
echo substr($src, $start, $end);
```