# PHP split string by <img> and break output

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am have some HTML content, and I need to parse it, get all the images. Then print out the whole content but running a PHP class instance in every occurrence of the image

```
This is the content

<?php $content = 'Some text
<p>A paragraph</p>
<img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
More text
<img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="200">'; ?>
```

I need to be able to get the images and run a class method with the output.

So the result would be something like

```
<?php echo 'Some text
<p>A paragraph</p>';

$this->Image('image1.jpg', PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $y_offset, 116, 85);
echo 'More text';
$this->Image('image2.jpg', PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $y_offset, 116, 85);
```

But obviouly I imagine it would have to be a loop or something that does it automatically

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Comment: Downvoting because your question does not show any effort to solve your problem - you are simply asking us to code for you.

Comment: Aha, I had no idea of where to start from. Anyway @RobertRossmann GAL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the entire HTML snippet to TcPDF as you mentioned in your comment, you'll need to parse the snippet with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and loop through each child node deciding how to handle them appropriately.

The catch with the snippet you've provided above is that it isn't a complete HTML document, thus `DOMDocument` will wrap it in `<html>` and `<body>` tags when parsing it, loading the following structure internally:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Some text
        <p>A paragraph</p>
        <img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
        More text
        <img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </body>
</html>
```

This caveat is easily worked around, however, by building on @hakre's answer in the thread I linked to below. My recommendation would be something along the lines of the following:

```
// Load the snipped into a DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

// Use DOMXPath to retrieve the body content of the snippet
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$data = $xpath->evaluate('//html/body');

// <body> is now $data[0], so for readability we do this
$body = $data[0];

// Now we loop through the elements in your original snippet
foreach ($body->childNodes as $node) {
    switch ($node->nodeName) {
        case 'img':
            // Get the value of the src attribute from the img element
            $src = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
            $this->Image($src, PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $y_offset, 116, 85);
            break;
        default:
            // Pass the line to TcPDF as a normal paragraph
            break;
    }
}
```

This way, you can easily add additional `case 'blah':` blocks to handle other elements which may appear in your `$content` snippets and handle them appropriately, and the content will be processed in the correct order without breaking the original flow of the text. :)

***-- Original answer.*** Will work if you just want to extract the image sources and process them elsewhere independently of the rest of the content.

You can match all the `<img>` tags in your `$content` string by using a regular expression:

```
/<img(?:[\s\w="]+)src="([^"]+)"(?:[\s\w="]*)\/?>/i
```

A live breakdown of the regex which you can play with to see how it works is here: http://regex101.com/r/tS5xY9

You can use this regex with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to retrieve all of the image tags from within your `$content` variable as follows:

```
$matches = array();
$num = preg_match_all('/<img(?:[\s\w="]+)src="([^"]+)"(?:[\s\w="]*)\/?>/i', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The `PREG_SET_ORDER` constant tells `preg_match_all()` to store its results in a manner which is more easily looped through when producing output, as the first index on the array (i.e., `$matches[0]`, `$matches[1]`, etc) will contain the complete set of matches from the regular expression. In the case of the regex above, `$matches[0]` will contain the following:

```
array(
    0 => '<img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200">',
    1 => 'image1.jpg',
)
```

You can now loop through `$matches` as `$key => $match` and pass `$match[1]` to your `$this->Image()` method.

Alternatively, if you don't want to loop through, you can just access each `src` attribute directly from `$matches` as `$matches[0][1]`, `$matches[1][1]`, etc.

If you need to be able to access the other attributes within the tags, then I recommend using the `DOMDocument` method provided by @hakre on [Get img src with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php). If you just need to access the `src` attribute, then using `preg_match_all()` is faster and more efficient as it does not need to load the entire DOM of the snippet into memory as objects to provide you with the data you need.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Awesome! @TwoWholeWorms works great, but I still need a way of breaking $content each time there is an image, execute the Class method, then continue output of $content.
I know it seems messy, but unfortunately I am working with TcPDF

Comment: @PatrickQ, Martin: I mis-read the question slightly. The answer I've given will work if you just want to get all the image sources disregarding the rest of the information. If you want to interleave them with the rest of the text, then you'll need to use the DOMParser on the whole chunk and loop through each node individually deciding how to handle them within a loop. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: @PatrickQ, Martin: See updated answer. This should do exactly what's needed. Had to muck around with a test file for a bit to figure it out, and learnt something myself in the process. ;)

Comment: I usually find that I learn more by answering questions than by asking them :)

Answer (score 1):

You could build a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) or [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser) to find out where the images are.

You're looking for two tokens at the beginning: `<img` and the respective closing `>`. A starting point for this could be something like this:

```
$text = "hello <img src='//first.jpg'> there <img src='//second.jpg'>";
$pos  = 0;

while (($opening = strpos($text, '<img', $pos)) !== FALSE) {

    // Find the next closing bracket's location
    $closing = strpos($text, '>', $opening);
    $length = ($closing - $opening) + 1; // Add one for the closing '>'

    $img_tag = substr($text, $opening, $length);

    var_dump($img_tag);

    // Update the loop position with our closing tag to advance the lexer
    $pos = $closing;
}
```

You're going to have to then build methods to scan for the img tags. You can also add your PDF methods in the loop, too.

Another more manageable approach could be to build a class that walks through each character. It'd first look for an opening '<' character, then check if the next three are 'img', and if so proceed to scan for the src, height, width attributes respectively. This is more work but is way more flexible – you'll be able to scan for much more than just your image tags.