# php preg_match find url without specific domain name

Tags: php, preg-match

I can get the all images's url in this case.

```
$str='<img src="http://facebook.com/img1.gif" /><img src="http://yahoo.com/img2.png" /><img src="http://google.com/img3.jpg" />';
preg_match_all('/<img src=(.*)\>/U', $str, $match);
```

but if i want to get the url without "http://google.com" how can i edit this code?
like this:

```
"http://facebook.com/img1.gif"
"http://yahoo.com/img2.png"
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: i think you try this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php]

Comment: Thanks, but this post not my want, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
    $str='<img src="http://facebook.com/img1.gif" /><img src="http://yahoo.com/img2.png" /><img src="http://google.com/img3.jpg" />';
    echo "<pre>";
      preg_match_all('/<img(.*)src(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $str, $result);
  print_r($result[4]);
```

this may be help you, i knw this way is not a correct way

Comment: thank you a lot, its helpful, i will think about how to fix it up. thank you very much

Comment: `how to fix it up means ??`