# How can I set all HTML code display except image HTML code

Tags: php, html, string, image, tags

Please see the picture below.
I need to set my page like below.

I'm using PHP,
to show the HTML code I got success.

```
<?php
$post = "<p>I like this</p>";
$get_post = htmlspecialchars($post);
?>
```

and the result will be :`<p>I like this</p>` <-- All html code display.

But now, if I have an image file,

```
<img src="logo.png"/>
```

It won't display the image, but html display.

What I want is, how can I set all HTML code display except image HTML code `<img>`?

Please see the image below for example.

[image]

Additional Information

```
1. We only have 1 variable, that's $post
2. Assume $post retrieve from database

Example 1: $post = "<html><p>a</p><img src='logo.png'/></html>";
Example 2: $post = "<img src='logo.png'/>";
```

Please see the picture above for example.

Comment: so for image you want an output but not for other tags ??

Comment: so the Image tag is coming in the middle of some tags or you are getting it direct `<img src="logo.png"/>`

Comment: @zan getting it direct, please.

Comment: Hard to say, but `strip_tags()` http://php.net/strip_tags could be an option. You can choose which ones you want or don't want stripped out.

Comment: you mean that image is displayed as an image not displaying code?

Comment: Yes correct @JeanGkol

Answer (score 0):

I think concat will do the thing. Comments are welcomed.

```
<?php
$post1 = "<p>I like this</p>";
$image= "<img src="logo.png"/>";
$post2= "<p>I like this Too</p>";
$get_post = htmlspecialchars($post1)." ".$image." ".htmlspecialchars($post2);
?>
```

Update

use htmlspecialchars_decode()

for img src you can visit
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php) can solve your question.

Comment: Hi, how about if I have just $post1? In $post1, I want the function detect show all HTML code except, so all html code will display except <img>

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the string have one img tag, then use if condition to get the output:

```
$post = "<img src='logo.png'/>";
//$post = '<p>I like this</p>';

if(strpos($post, "<img") != false)
{
     echo $post;
}else{
    $get_post = htmlspecialchars($post);
    echo $get_post;
}
```

Comment: Hi @zan, How about if in $post, there is a <span> and I want the <span> code display?

Comment: Hi, give us all the possible cases so that we can give you  answer,

Comment: Hi Zan, please see my additional information in my question. Please see the image for example. I think you will understand about my question.

Comment: do you want example one to display image

Answer (score 0):

Still confused of your question for my bad English.
Perhaps this helps.

```
<?php
$post='<img src="image/america.png"/>';
echo $post;
 ?>
```

**UPDATED**:

```
<?php
$post='<img src="image/america.png"/>';
//$post='<p>Hallo</p>';
$detect=substr($post,0,4);
if ($detect){
echo $post;
}
else{
$get_post = htmlspecialchars($post);
echo $get_post;
}
?>
```