# How to get the hyperlink from an image when given its url

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing, simple-html-dom

I was wondering is it possible to get the hyperlink of an image if the image url is given for eg: I have a webpage say (http://www.example.com)
with an image 
 for eg :

```
<a href="http://example.com/12344/623/2"><img id="img" src="http://example.com/623/5602225.jpg" alt="The Image" name="img" height="1140" width="800"></a>
```

I was thinking is it possible to get this

http://example.com/12344/623/2

when i give

http://example.com/623/5602225.jpg

as an input in php and CURL?

Comment: In your question `http://example.com/12344/623/2` and `http://example.com/623/5602225.jpg` does not related to each other except `623`. could you pls be clear ?

Comment: Its ok, If you edit the question with exact param it would be easy to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Comment: its not like that i am inputting the image url ie src and i want to get the href attribuute associated withit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to parse the html.

As you tagged SimpleHtmlDom:

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
//example html
$html = '<a href="http://example.com/12344/623/1"><img id="img" src="http://example.com/623/5602224.jpg" alt="The Image" name="img" height="1140" width="800"></a>';
$html .= '<a href="http://example.com/12344/623/2"><img id="img" src="http://example.com/623/5602225.jpg" alt="The Image" name="img" height="1140" width="800"></a>';
$html .= '<a href="http://example.com/12344/623/3"><img id="img" src="http://example.com/623/5602226.jpg" alt="The Image" name="img" height="1140" width="800"></a>';

//the image url to search for
$img = 'http://example.com/623/5602225.jpg';

//Note if you want to get the html from a url and not a string,
// use $som = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$url = $dom->find('img[src='.$img.']', 0)->parent->href;
//$url equals http://example.com/12344/623/2
```