# Extract src from image tag output in Web Services using PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match

```
"<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"http://localhost/example-local/sites/example/files/styles/thumbnail/public/news-story/gallery-images/Desert.jpg?itok=bqyr-vpK\" width=\"100\" height=\"75\" alt=\"\" /><blockquote class=\"image-field-caption\">\r\n  <p>Desert</p>\n</blockquote>\r\n"
```

I need to extract only `src` from this string

I've tried this but its not working for me:

```
preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i');
```

Comment: Don't use regex; use a HTML parser in the language / platform you are working with. Much more reliable. Example for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Answer (score -1):

As pekka said in his comment, PHP has built in tools already for pulling out tags and things of that nature.  Your string would be a good example for when to use PHP DOM.

That being said, using regex, I suppose you could just match everything between `src=\"` and the closing `\"`.  Pretty simple to do that:

```
src=\\"(.*?)\\"
```

Together, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

// SET OUR DEFAULT STRING
$string = "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"http://localhost/example-local/sites/example/files/styles/thumbnail/public/news-story/gallery-images/Desert.jpg?itok=bqyr-vpK\" width=\"100\" height=\"75\" alt=\"\" /><blockquote class=\"image-field-caption\">\r\n  <p>Desert</p>\n</blockquote>\r\n";

// USE PREG MATCH TO FIND THE STRING AND SAVE IT IN $matches
preg_match('~src=\\"(.*?)\\"~i', $string, $matches);

// PRINT IT OUT
print $matches[1];
```

That will give you this:

```
http://localhost/example-local/sites/example/files/styles/thumbnail/public/news-story/gallery-images/Desert.jpg?itok=bqyr-vpK
```

Or you could combine the two lines using preg_replace if that tickled your fancy:

```
print preg_replace('~.*?src=\\"(.*?)\\".*~is', '$1', $string);
```

This basically just matches everything and overwrites the entire string with whatever it found in the `(.*?)`.

Here is a working demo:

https://ideone.com/OvlaQZ