# Extract the value of src attribute with explode function or similar

Tags: php, explode, meta, schema.org, omeka

I have this string:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/omeka3/files/square_thumbnails/a1641b89b518599b049efa6017f92040.jpg" alt="altText" title="Title">
```

I want to extract the value of the src attribute, to create a meta element like this:

```
<meta itemprop='thumbnailUrl' content='http://localhost:8080/omeka3/files/square_thumbnails/a1641b89b518599b049efa6017f92040.jpg' />
```

I tried the explode function:

```
$img_tag = item_image('square_thumbnail');
$thumbnailUrl = explode("=",$img_tag);
echo "<meta itemprop='thumbnailUrl' content='".$thumbnailUrl[1]."'/>";
```

But the result is:

```
<meta itemprop='thumbnailUrl' content='"http://localhost:8080/omeka3/files/square_thumbnails/a1641b89b518599b049efa6017f92040.jpg" alt'/>
```

There's any way to indicate the limit of the string at .jpg, with explode() or another function?

Thanks!

Comment: here is your answer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Comment: Either use a regular expression for the extraction (php's `preg_...()` functions) or a DOM handler extension.

Comment: Side note: In HTML5/Microdata, you [must](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) use `link` instead of `meta`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOMDocument class (available in PHP 5 and higher) to parse the src attribute of your `<img>` HTML tag:

```
    $input = '<img src="http://localhost:8080/omeka3/files/square_thumbnails/a1641b89b518599b049efa6017f92040.jpg" alt="altText" title="Title">';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($input);
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    if ($nodes->length == 1) {
        echo $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    }
```