# Getting the img src using a complex xpath with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath

I'd like to have a function to return the src of an image. The image should be selected by an xpath, which shall be passed to the function:

```
function getImgUrl($html, $xpath) {
    $xpathkram = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));

    $src = $xpathkram->evaluate('string(' . $xpath . '@src)');
    return $src; 
}
$xpath = '//*[@id="watch7-sidebar-modules"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li/div[2]/a/span/img';
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNBjMRvOB5M";

echo getImgUrl($html, $xpath));
```

Yet for some reason it refuses to work and states a `DOMXPath::evaluate(): Invalid expression` in line four.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131137/4256351

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in code: missed closing parenthesis after `file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNBjMRvOB5M";` and two brackets instead of one here `echo getImgUrl($html, $xpath));`.

Comment: I edited the code in an effort to make my problem more clear. These syntax errors slipped in in the process.

Answer (score 0):

First add attribure 'src' to $xpath query as '/@src':

```
$xpath = '//*[@id="watch7-sidebar-modules"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li/div[2]/a/span/img/@src';
```

Your mistake here:

```
$src = $xpathkram->evaluate('string(' . $xpath . '@src)');
```

You shall write:

```
$src = $xpathkram->evaluate( $xpath );
```

The result is that you receive will be DOMNodeList object. To get text from it:

```
$list = getImgUrl($html, $xpath);

foreach ($list as $item){
    var_dump($item->textContent);
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, yet it still does not work when the xpath starts with /html/..
example: [link](https://blog.google/topics/google-europe/zaha-hadid-serpentine-galleries-virtual-reality/), `/html/body/main/article/section[3]/div/nav/a[2]/figure/picture/img/@src`

Comment: try to start expression with ".//"

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: Stangely it only seems to work if I use some sort of class or id as a selector (with brackets)

Comment: In yours case is no matter from what symbol you start your expression - with dot or without dot. To get result, use this expression ".//main/article/section[3]/div/nav/a[2]/figure/picture/source/source/img/@src"