# To make html explode with php?

Tags: php

I draw data with the bot, but I can get it in html. I want to separate the url in html I tried it with explode() but I didn't succeed.

part of the code I want to get url with php

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D4r0FAqHl8HpymNXL78pSjskKl1f1WDU4jGIpTI0MiGR8xRfOCk5TiJH8dn9MdKEoyw=s100" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D4r0FAqHl8HpymNXL78pSjskKl1f1WDU4jGIpTI0MiGR8xRfOCk5TiJH8dn9MdKEoyw=s200 2x" class="T75of sHb2Xb" aria-hidden="true" alt="Kapak resmi" itemprop="image">
```

Comment: not sure I see your explode function?

Comment: use a html parser

Comment: Try using some parser like https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

Comment: Please go read [ask], and then give us a proper explanation of what your problem actually is. Show us what you tried, instead of just stating “didn’t succeed”.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [Dom Parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Dom Parser is very good at dealing with XML as well as HTML

```
<?php
$html_string = '<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D4r0FAqHl8HpymNXL78pSjskKl1f1WDU4jGIpTI0MiGR8xRfOCk5TiJH8dn9MdKEoyw=s100" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D4r0FAqHl8HpymNXL78pSjskKl1f1WDU4jGIpTI0MiGR8xRfOCk5TiJH8dn9MdKEoyw=s200 2x" class="T75of sHb2Xb" aria-hidden="true" alt="Kapak resmi" itemprop="image">';

//Create a new DOM document
$doc = new \DOMDocument();

 //Parse the HTML.
$doc->loadHTML($html_string);

//Get the image tag to parse
$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img"); // DOMNodeList Object

//Craete array to add all DOMElement value
$image = array();
$i= 0;
foreach($img as $item) { // DOMElement Object
    //DOMElement::getAttribute — Returns value of attribute
    $image[$i]['img']['src'] = $item->getAttribute('src');
    $image[$i]['img']['srcset'] = $item->getAttribute('src');
     $i++;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($image);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/19lIt)