# Get Image src using regex

Tags: php, html

I have here a simple regex to get the `src` attribute of an image from an html code saved in my datebase.

```
$imagePattern = '/img src=(["\'])(.*?)\1/';
preg_match_all($imagePattern , $html, $matched);
var_dump($matched);die();
```

I get the `src` only when the `<img>` tag is formatted like `<img src='test.png' id='test_image'>` but when the image tag is formatted like `<img  id='test_image' src='test.png'>`, I can't get the `src`. Yes I know my regex is specific if `img tag` and `src attribute` is consecutive. How can I get the src of an image if the tag is `img` and has `src` attribute? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get img src with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!