# Get a Movie Rate Form from IMDB

Tags: php, regex

I need to get a Movie rating form from IMDB form image alt

```
<img width="44" height="15" title="PG_13" class="absmiddle" src="http://i.media-imdb.com/images/SF9c87441dc1ac3081c7de5a78d8864764/certificates/us/pg_13.png" **alt="PG_13"**>
```

**My Code (WRONG):**

```
$arr['rate'] = $this->match('/<img class=\"absmiddle\" src=\"\(.*?)\" alt=\"\(.*?)">/ms', $html, 1);
```

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<img width="44" height="15" title="PG_13" class="absmiddle" src="http://i.media-imdb.com/images/SF9c87441dc1ac3081c7de5a78d8864764/certificates/us/pg_13.png" alt="PG_13">';
preg_match('<img[^<]+class="absmiddle" src="([^"]+)" alt="([^"]+)"/i', $text, $a);
$src = $a[1];
$alt = $a[2];
```