# How to get data between <td> elements with Regex and Php

Tags: php, html, regex

How can I get the "85 mph" from this html code with PHP + Regex ? 
I couldn't come up with right regex
This is the code
http://pastebin.com/ffRH9K9Q

```
    <td align="left">Los Angeles</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">Wind Speed:</td>
    <td align="left">85 mph</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">Snow Load:</td>
    <td align="left">0 psf</td>
```

*(simplified example)*

Comment: I think this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It doesn't give any results as array. I will share everything that I've tried.

Comment: Your example (malformed) markup is a key reason why you can't reliably parse HTML with a Regex.

Comment: @tskuzzy The zalgo thing is funny, but totally unhelpful to an inexperienced user who may never have heard of DOM parsing and doesn't understand why they're getting made fun of. That link really needs a companion link to a primer on better parser options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: @octern that would probably be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've heard already about not using regex for the job, so I won't talk about that.
Let's try something here. Perhaps not the ideal solution, but could work for you.

```
    <?php
       $data = 'your table';
       preg_match ('|<td align="left">(.*)mph</td>|Usi', $data, $result);
       print_r($result);  // Your result shoud be in here
```

You could need some trimming or taking whitespaces into account in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment that links to the post about NOT PARSING HTML WITH REGEX is important.  That said, try something like [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead.  That should get you started traversing the DOM with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on DorkRawk's suggestion (in the hope of providing a relatively succinct answer that isn't overwhelming for a beginner), try this:

```
<?php

$yourhtml = '<td align="left">Los Angeles</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">Wind Speed:</td>
    <td align="left">85 mph</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">Snow Load:</td>
    <td align="left">0 psf</td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourhtml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$matches = $xpath->query('//td[.="Wind Speed:"]/following-sibling::td');

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match->nodeValue."\n\n";
}
```