# How to parse HTML with regular expression?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I have HTML document which contains many records with following format:

```
<tr><td>af</td><td>Afrikaans</td></tr>
```

Please, tell me, how can I extract "af" and "Afrikaans" using regular expression? Thank you.

Comment: don't do that and use simplexml for e.g.

Comment: that's not an XML that's HTML

Comment: [Some men just want to watch the world burn.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: the code sample suggests its html. Avoid using regex with markup languages. traverse the tree to extract the required info.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid, and have made a mistake. Please, help me with code

Comment: This is a never ending discussion... Look at this topic for a similar question and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109661/how-to-get-data-between-td-elements-with-regex-and-php/11110795#11110795

Comment: please see if this helps - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple example to get you started, but depending on the structure of the HTML you will need to make some tweaks:

```
$s = <<<EOM
<tr><td>af</td><td>Afrikaans</td></tr>
EOM;

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);
foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

See also, the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/domdocument) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM, SAX, SimpleXML, PHPQuesry, tidy instead of Regular expressions for parsing XML