# Unable to identify whats wrong with my Regex

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

I am trying to parse a webpage and get the full images. E.g

```
<html>

<body>
<a href='1.jpg'><img src='tn1.jpg /></a>
<a href='2.jpg'><img src='tn2.jpg /></a>
<a href='3.jpg'><img src='tn3.jpg /></a>
<a href='4.jpg'><img src='tn4.jpg /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am trying to capture them to get the full thumbnails which are:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

My PHP Regex code is:

```
$text = file_get_contents($website); //Get webpage

preg_match_all("~$[0-9](.*?)\.jpg~i", $text, $matches);
```

But when I run it, the $matches array is empty yet the paths are there in the webiste. What might be wrong with my Regex?

INFO: All images follow a pattern and are all a number followed by .jpg

Comment: This has been asked many times. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406453/how-to-get-link-from-img-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend the usage of regex to parse html, but if you don't want to do this properly, here's a regex that does the trick: `/(?<=['"])\d+\.jpg/i`

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/xC8nP2

The problem with your regex is the misuse of the `$`-anchor.

Comment: Sorry..maybe I forgot to write that there are other .jpgs. Your Regex will also match another that looks something like this `<img class="last bottom" src="55-tmp/templates/thumbs/thumbs_62.jpg >` it will match it as 62.jpg - which is not what I was aiming for.

I need the regex to match only those that are exactly `<a href='[number].jpg'` e.g `<a href="1.jpg"`

Comment: With those '", how does one write that in preg_match_all? I'm trying this `preg_match_all('/(?<=['"])\d+\.jpg/i', $text, $matches);` and its spewing an error in my editor.

Comment: I assume you fixed your problem? And no problem!