# How do I extract a specific substring from a given HTML tag, without knowing for certain its length?

Tags: php, html

I want to do something like:

```
<?php
$text = "<font style='color: #fff'>";
$replaceandshow = str_replace("<font style=\"?\">", "the font style is ?", $text);
echo $replaceandshow;
?>
```

For example the ? is color: #fff, but I want that PHP will trace it by itself, Is it possible + If it's possible , How can I do that?

P.S: Someone gave me a code but it's now working, it displays a White page for me.

```
<?php
$colorstring = "<font style='#fff'>";
$searchcolor = preg_replace('[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}','[font style=$1]Test[/font]',$colorstring);
echo $searchcolor;
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting white page because error reporting is turned off. The error in your code is missing delimiter in `preg_replace`. And additionally, to use back-referencing you should enclose the expression required to match in parentheses.

```
preg_replace('/([a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})/','the font style is $1',$colorstring);
```

shall give the correct output.

You might consider using a more constrictive expression because the current expression is very open to matching other strings like "FFFont". Another thing to note is that the expression may result in output like.

```
<font style='color: the color is #fff'>
```

Try:

```
/<font style='color: #([a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})'>/
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to pull basically any attribute out of any HTML you can use php XML parsing to do this.

```
<?php
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br><font style='color: #fff;'>hellow</font><a href='www.somesite.com' title='some title'>some site</a></body></html>");
$xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
$fonts=$xml->xpath('//font');
foreach ($fonts as $font) {
    echo 'font style = '.$font['style']."<br />";
}

$as=$xml->xpath('//a');
foreach ($as as $a) {
    echo 'href = '.$a['href'] . ' title = ' . $a['title']."<br />";
}
?>
```

That will return:

```
font style = color: #fff;
href = www.somesite.com title = some title
```

You can use a different foreach loop for each HTML tag you need to extract and then output any of the attributes you want.

Answer based on [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: No, not just for the style. might be to <a href=""> and all other kind of stuff.

Comment: So you want a function that pulls the attributes of any HTML?

Comment: @Aviv.A see new answer you can get any attributes from any HTML with it.

Comment: This solution may suit you better than writing a different preg_match for every element you need.

Comment: Thank You, didn't knew I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with simple `style` attributes:

```
$text = "<font style='color: #fff'>";
preg_match("/<font style=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]>/", $text, $matches);
echo "The font style is ".$matches[1];
```

For anything more complicated (ex: if it includes quotes), you'll need to use a HTML parser, such as http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php