# php - get the source of an image

Tags: php, image

I need to get all the source values from all image inside a container. I'm having some difficulty with this.

Allow me to explain the process. 
All the data comes from a database. Inside the backofficce the user enter all the text and the image inside a textarea. To separate the text with the image the user must enter a pagebreak.
Let's go to the code

```
while ($rowClients = mysql_fetch_array($rsClients)) {
    $result = $rowClients['content'];
    $resultExplode = explode('<!-- pagebreak -->', $result);
    // with resultExplode[0] I get the code and with resultExplde[1] I get the image

    // Now with I want to get only the src value from resultExplode[1]
```

I already tried with `strip_tags`

```
$imageSrc = strip_tags($resultadoExplode[1]);
```

but it doesn't print anything.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php) but without success. I stopped in the first print_r.

Can anyone help me??

Thanks

Comment: What exactly didn't work about the solution proposed in the other question?

Comment: Try using PHP [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Without a sample of the text I can only assume your text is html like: <img src="image.png"/> please confirm this

Comment: @nyarlathotep All the process. But for start I couldn't print the array of all images like it does in the first print

Comment: @user794035: "I couldn't" is a very imprecise statement. What exactly didn't work about it? It probably did execute properly, but just didn't print anything, right? if print_r prints nothing, then your input is probably wrong ;)

Comment: @Waygood yes its an html tag like this <img title="titleImg" src="/path/to/file.png" alt="alttext" width="111" height="28" />

Comment: @nyarlathotep yes, the print_r doesn't print nothing. I'm not understanding how can my input is wrong. Can you explain ?? Thanks

Comment: @user794035: well if the regular expression doesn't find any matches, it probably means that the given string doesn't contain any img tags.

Comment: @nyarlathotep ok I'll try it again.

Comment: what would help would be the output of print_r($resultExplode[1]), where you say you "can see the images";

Comment: yes with that command I can see the image. That's why a I think the that the input isn't wrong.

Comment: result of print_r($resultExplode); not just [1] would be more informative

Comment: ah ok. What I got was this: Array ( [0] =>

“1 - Morbi elit nunc, molestie at, ultrices eu, eleifend eu, lorem. Sed pede orci, volutpat sed, congue vel, gravida non, lacus.Vivamus quis metus. Mauris ligula est, auctor vitae, pretium eget, hendrerit

[1] => 

small.png
) Array ( [0] =>

“ 2- Morbi elit nunc, molestie at, ultrices eu, eleifend eu, lorem. Sed pede orci, volutpat sed, congue vel, gravida non, lacus.Vivamus 

[1] =>

benteler.png
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

continuing with the previous code I worked with the split function.

So I start to strip the  tags. This way I get the img isolated from the rest.

```
$image = strip_tags($resultExplode[1],"<img>");
```

Because all the img has the same structure like this: `<img width="111" height="28" alt="alternative text" src="/path/to/the/file.png" title="title of the image">`

I split this string, using " as a delimiter

```
$imgSplit = split('"', $image);
$src = $imgSplit[3];
```

Voilá. It's working

What do you say about this procedeure??

Answer (score 0):

try foreach, if you can't print it out.. (if that's the problem)

```
  foreach($resultExplode as $key => $value){
    echo "[".$key."]".$value;
    }
```

Comment: if I print_r($resultExplode[1]) I can see the image. That's what your code does. I want to get the source of the image. I said printing the source code, for test, for having a starting point.