# Replace All HTML img tags with text inside their ALT

Tags: php, preg-replace, image, alt

for example:

INPUT:

```
<img "img1.gif" alt="Donkey"><BR>
<img "img2.gif" alt="Horse"><BR>
<img "img3.gif" alt="Orangutan"><BR>
```

OUTPUT

```
Donkey
Horse
Orangutan
```

looked around for this but no cigar. Any ideas? thnx!

Comment: no only preg_replace or the like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a quick solution use [preg_replace()](http://uk.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$text = '<img img1.gif" alt="Donkey"><BR>
<img img2.gif" alt="Horse"><BR>
<img img3.gif" alt="Orangutan"><BR>';

$replace = preg_replace('/<img(.*)alt="(.*)"\>/', "$2", $text);
echo $replace;
```

Comment: ... followed by `br2nl()`? :)

Comment: ... he first said he wants those `<BR>`'s :)

Comment: beautiful. thanks. needed this for print view. surprised it's not so common

Comment: slightly more reliable:preg_replace('/<img[^>]*alt="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/', "$2", $text);

Comment: Thanks so much to this answer.. +1

Answer (score 3):

Feeling generous today, here's da c0dez:

```
$html =<<<EOS
<img "img1.gif" alt="Donkey"><BR>
<img "img2.gif" alt="Horse"><BR>
<img "img3.gif" alt="Orangutan"><BR>
EOS;

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('alt'), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have looked around a lot - look at this quite similar question:

[How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: thought may be a simpler way to do this for only ALT

Comment: It is, as you can see from the other answers. But you should really try solving it yourself first (e.g. by selecting the useful bits from the aforementioned post) before having other people write your code for you.

Comment: ok. sorry. thanks for help. thought this might be a common problem that would be useful for others also.