# Find a match, then grab some html before and after it

Tags: php

In php, I am scraping some html from one of my other external sites. I'm performing the scrape and getting all of the page html in a php string. I need to find the first .png file type in this string. I then need to just grab the html from this point to find the beginning http before it AND grab the html after it just before the following characters begin "\u002522". Any ideas?

So:

```
<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><p>Here's a nice image</p><img src="http://www.exampleurl.com/image.png?id=35435646&v=5647\\u002522"/></body></html>
```

Would turn into:

```
http://www.exampleurl.com/image.png?id=35435646&v=5647
```

I've looked everywhere for combining all these things at the same time, but to no luck :(

Comment: `DOMDocument`, create a `DOMXPath`, query for `//img/@src[contains(.,".png")][0]`, get the `->value` of that `DOMAttr`. [DOM refererence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before and it worked great for me. [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Then just clean up the URL and split on //.

Let me know if I need to be more specific.