# Get images from external page using PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the URLs of all images of a given external page using PHP. Is this possible? And if so, how is it done?

Comment: take a look at file_get_contents or curl, DomDocument & DomXPath ...

Comment: Been a few months now and you have still not accepted a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
<?php
    $mypage = file_get_contents('http://www.somepage.com/');
    echo $mypage;
?>
```

Some times You should use [curl functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

[**Please look at this answear!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$directory = "http://somewebsite.tld/directory/to/images";

foreach($images as $image)
{
    $relative_path = $directory.basename($image);
    $r .= '<img src="'.$relative_path.'" />';
    return $r;
}
```

This will generate a HTML list of all images in that directory.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('/<img src\="(?P<src>(.*)(?:jpe?g|png|gif))"(.*)>/',$page,$srcs);

print_r($srcs[1]);
```

`$url` is the url of the page you want to get images from.

The regular expression gets images with extension jpg, jpeg, png and gif, you can add more extensions separated by `|`.

In `$srcs[1]` array you have all the urls of all the images.