# get image src from HTML with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have HTML like

```
<td class="td_scheda_modello_dati">

       <img src="/webapp/safilo/gen_img/p_verde.gif" width="15" height="15" alt="" border="0">

</td>
```

I want to extract the img src from this HTML using preg_match_all().

I have done this

```
preg_match_all('#<td class=td_scheda_modello_dati>(.*)<td>#',$detail,$detailsav);
```

It should give the whole  img tag.But it doesn't give me the img tag. So what changes should be done to get the specific value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: Could you please close the question if my answered helped?

Comment: @AliGajani I got help from multiple answers! So, can't mark a single answer as accepted! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MJQ: I agree, but still mark "some answer" as a green!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Long story short:** [ideone](http://ideone.com/91iNMy)

You should not use Regex, but instead an HTML parser. Here's how.

```
<?php
$html = '<img src="/webapp/safilo/gen_img/p_verde.gif" width="15" height="15" alt="" border="0">';
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
echo $src;
?>
```

Comment: While an HTML parser is the ideal solution, I have a feeling he is looking for a much more short term solution.  Also the parser might invalidly `correct` required `quirks` on output.

Comment: I think he might not be aware that an HTML parser can be used to achieve such tasks instead of Regex. I have given him a decent solution for that matter.

Comment: Well +1 for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$html_text =  '<td class="td_scheda_modello_dati">   
            <img src="/webapp/safilo/gen_img/p_verde.gif" width="15" height="15" alt=""    border="0"></td>';

preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $html_text , $res_array ) ;

print_r($res_array);
```

Comment: Kumar, I have multiple img tags in html, what if i just want the src of tags that are in <td class="td_scheda_modello_dati"> ... </td> ???

Comment: MJQ, I'm all for quick regex fixes but if there are multiple images in each table cell it will require 2 regexes to get all the `src` and be more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `s` modifier after your regex. The default behavior for the dot character is not to match newlines (which your example has).

Something like:

```
preg_match_all('#<td class=td_scheda_modello_dati>(.*)</td>#s',$detail,$detailsav);
```

Should do the trick.

It's worth reading up a bit on modifiers, the more you do with regex the more useful they become.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Edit: also, just realized that the code posted was missing a closing td tag (it was `<td>` instead of `</td>`). Fixed my example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<img[^>]*src="([^"]*/gen_img/p_verde.gif)"`