# How can I fetch the thumbnail image in the other homepage by URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I knew the internet address which has images that i want to show. 
Then, Without image download, how can i get the image view in my homepage as like facebook?

I had the image website address.

Please help me!

Comment: You had it and lost it?

Comment: I don't know about jquery/javascript but you can use PHP to get the html code from an url, then parse it with php to get all images on that page, then pick one to show or download to your own server.

Comment: How can php get images from the url?? please, Let me know the php code or php function name

Comment: See this question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php

Comment: Thanks a lot, Switching Brains!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was going to write this as a comment, but it's too long:

---

**CORS**

You should be aware about [`CORS` policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on different web hosts. You have the tag of `ajax`, which means you're going to use an `XHR` (`XMLHttpRequest`) to another host

The reason I write this is because although you can access other web sites through `CURL` (if using PHP), using a JS (`Ajax`) request will probably lead to being knocked back

If you're going to "import" image `SRC`'s from a website, you'll likely have to do it with a `HTTP` request, rather than an asynchronous ajax one