# How to filter any given number of html tags through php

Tags: php, html, image, dom, random

I'm working on a project in which I want to display randomly any given number of results suppose, I have six `<html>` tags of image and I only want to display three randomly so that every time we refresh the page it show randomly any three image out of any six

I'm using html code for an example

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example1.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image1.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example2.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image2.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example3.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image3.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example4.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image4.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example5.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image5.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=1>
      <a href="http://example6.com">
        <div>
          <img src="image6.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Out of this Six Images I only want to show any three Images Each time through php. Is it possible and how can I do that?
Hope you may find any better solution.
Also i want to display Other tags like link inthe image and some more  tags so that i can display images in a better way through css so I think it can be done by switch statement more easily

Comment: Put the filenames in an array.  `array_rand()` and then `foreach`. Or `shuffle()` and then loop 3 times.

Comment: suppose I have to show some other things with each image can you show me how to do that

Comment: What _other things_?

Comment: Other tags like link inthe image and some more `<div>` tags so that i can display images in a better way through css

Comment: @learner see my answer in case if you want a php code that could get defined number of random images with its links from existing page into another page. i think that's what you are trying to do and hope it helps. enjoy :)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php and work that into your code.

Comment: @learner "Answer should be perfect I want to retreve two random from two array with the name index number" - show us your arrays: what you have in your sources.

Comment: I got my answer @NicholasVasilaki

Comment: @learner but no one got your bounty, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expanded **Morten**'s code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$images = array(
    array('img' => 'image1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example1.com', 'div' => 'class="d1"'),
    array('img' => 'image2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example2.com', 'div' => 'class="d2"'),
    array('img' => 'image3.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example3.com', 'div' => 'class="d3"'),
    array('img' => 'image4.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example4.com', 'div' => 'class="d4"'),
    array('img' => 'image5.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example5.com', 'div' => 'class="d5"'),
    array('img' => 'image6.jpg', 'url' => 'http://example6.com', 'div' => 'class="d6"')
);

// Selects 3 random array values and returns the key for each value
$randomkeys = array_rand($images, 3);

// Here we loop through the given index keys from the $images array.
// For each key we will then get the value from $images with the index $key
foreach ($randomkeys as $key) {
    // I end with PHP_EOL (End of line) so the source code will look a bit prettier.
    echo '<div class="1">' . PHP_EOL . '<a href="' . $images[$key]['url'] . '">' . PHP_EOL . '<div ' . $images[$key]['div'] . '>' . PHP_EOL . '<img src="' . $images[$key]['img'] . '">' . PHP_EOL . '</div>' . PHP_EOL . '</a></div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
https://3v4l.org/OAc6l

Comment: Why You have use '<div class=\"image\">'. Instead of this. '<div class="image">'

Comment: Because he just expanded my answer, @learner. The reason i chose that style was so i could use `{$images['key']}` directly instead of concattinating the string by writing `echo 'something ' . $images['key'] . ' something';`

Comment: @learner added divs for imgs, changed to long syntax, changed result URL

Comment: @learner I saw you  online 7 hours ago and 2 days ago, but you are not active at this question. Are you waiting while bounty will expire?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have a array with all the images. From that list, we randomly get the keys for 3 of the images. We then through a loop echo out the img tag:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$images = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg',
    'image4.jpg',
    'image5.jpg',
    'image6.jpg'
];

// Selects 3 random array values and returns the key for each value
$randomkeys = array_rand($images, 3);

// Here we loop through the given index keys from the $images array.
// For each key we will then get the value from $images with the index $key
foreach ($randomkeys as $key) {
    // I end with PHP_EOL (End of line) so the source code will look a bit prettier.
    echo "<div class=\"image\"><a href=\"{$images[$key]}\"><img src=\"{$images[$key]}\"></a></div>".PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If something was unclear, let me know

**Edit 1: Added more tags**
It's not hard to add more tags to the output. If you know how to echo string and variables you should be able to easy add more tags or change them the way you want.

As you can see in the update I have added the class `image` to the , and made the  link to the same path as the image so when you click it it will just open the image in the same window.

Comment: You can also just use the value that array_rand() returns instead of unnecessarily indexing into the array.

Comment: A "comma" instead of a "period" with echo is faster by a lot. A period creates a new string value, a comma just appends the value to the end.

Comment: `array_rand()` only returns the key(s) from a given array. You don't get the value from the array. Therefore you have to do the indexing into the array @pestilence669

Comment: I have edited the question i also want to display some Other tags like link inthe image and some more `<div>` tags so that i can display images in a better way through css

Comment: Added a <div> and a <a> tag as requested in the question comments. It shouldn't be too difficult to change it further, but if you occur on some problems, I'll be here to help you, @learner

Comment: @Morten As mentioned in the question you can see that i have used every time different url for different images so according to your given answer this cannot be possible because you are using same url for every image and i have mentioned a specific url for every image

Comment: @learner
UPD: just look at expanded Morten's code below.
 Use 2D array instead of 1D (vector) - in this way you can specify different URLs for different imgs, if I understand you correctly. Example: $images = array( array('img' => 'image1.jpg', 'link' => 'example1.com'), array('img' => 'image2.jpg', 'link' => 'example2.com') );

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
  $images=array('image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg','image6.jpg');
shuffle($images);
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
 echo '<img src="'.$images[$i].'" />';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Perfectly performant for the six image constraint. It really only becomes wasteful after a few dozen.

Comment: this answer is perfect, but it answers half of the OP's question, please try to also include the links (`<a></a>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can keep your src paths in an array. Then you can use array_rand() function to get random array index. 

For example:
<?php

$allImages = ["images1.jpg","images2.jpg","images3.jpg","images4.jpg","images5.jpg","images6.jpg"];

//this will return random keys of $allImages array
$randomKeys = array_rand($allImages, 3);

foreach($randomKeys as $key){ ?>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $allImages[$key] ?> " ></a></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how you can do this using php

Comment: I have edited the question i also want to display some Other tags like link inthe image and some more `<div>` tags so that i can display images in a better way through css

Comment: Ok then you can add whatever and however you want to add in the php for each loop.

Comment: I have edited my answer. No you can do whatever you want in the `div`, `a` or `img` tag`. In the `src` I just added the php variable to show the randomly chosen image paths. I this solves you problem. Please approve this answer. Best of luck.

Comment: I m using different url with all the images

Answer (score 0):

Like @AbraCadaver said.

```
<?php
// vim: set ts=4 sw=4 et:

$myImages = array_map(function($i) { return "/foo$i.jpg"; }, range(1, 6));

foreach (array_map('htmlspecialchars', array_map(function ($i) { global $myImages; return $myImages[$i]; }, array_rand($myImages, 3))) as $image)
    echo "<img src=\"$image\"/>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you mean if the page is already prepared ( may be the page is external webpage, or another page which is being already designed) i would use [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) and include the folder to the project.

**example.html**

```
<html>
<style>
img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>
 <body>
<div class=1>
<a href="http://example1.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (1).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>
<div class=1>
<a href="http://example2.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (2).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>      <div class=1>
<a href="http://example3.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (3).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>
<div class=1>
<a href="http://example4.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (4).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>
<div class=1>
<a href="http://example5.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (5).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>
<div class=1>
<a href="http://example6.com">
<div>                               
<img src="image (6).jpg" >                                     
</div>
</a></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**myphp.php**

```
/**echo '<style>
img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>';**/

//using Simple HTML DOM. This file is in Simple Html Dom folder downloaded
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('example.html');// you can write your external website file here www.external.com/index.html

// find all link
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    //echo $e->href . '<br>';
    $image_with_link['link'][]=$e->href;
// find all image
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    //echo $e->src . '<br>';
    $image_with_link['image'][]=$e->src;

//for debugging
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($image_with_link);
//echo '</pre>';

//loop number of times, here i want to display three images
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
//get random key from array
$rand=array_rand($image_with_link['image'],1);

//print 3 images with its links
echo '<a href="'.$image_with_link['link'][$i].'" />';
echo '<img src="'.$image_with_link['image'][$i].'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the code as one big string. Remove `<HTML>`, `</HTML>`, `<BODY>`, and `</BODY>` from that string. You can add them back whenever you want. Next, explode the string around `"<DIV "`. For the array that is created, add `"<DIV "` to the start of each element. You now have an array containing each div section which has each image and link you want. You can then pick ones at random from that array and insert as needed:

```
// remove HTML and BODY tags
    $remove1 = str_replace("<HTML>", "", $original);
    $remove2 = str_replace("<BODY>", "", $remove1);
    $remove3 = str_replace("</HTML>", "", $remove2);
    $cleaned = str_replace("</BODY>", "", $remove3);

// explode remaining code around "<DIV " so we have each division for each image
    $codeArray = explode("<DIV ", $cleaned);

// with our code sectioned in an array, add "<DIV " back to the start
// of each element in the array
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($codeArray); $x++){
        $codeArray[$x] =. "<DIV ";
    }

// the $codeArray now has $x elements of the sections that contain the 
// links and images you want.
// You can now randomly grab the div's that you want, by
// Shuffling that array, pick the first X images you want, and then
// echo back out the code you want.
    shuffle($codeArray);
    echo "<HTML>";
    echo "<BODY>";
    for ($x = 0; $x < $whateverNumberOfImagesYouWant; $x++){
        echo $codeArray[$x];
    }
    echo "</BODY>";
    echo "</HTML>";
```