# GET img src from array query results PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to take img src from record after a query:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = array(
     'id' => $row['ID_CONTENT'],
     'titolo' => $row['TITOLO'],
     'articolo' => $row['DESCRIZIONE'],
     'giorno' => $row['GIORNO'],
     'foto' => "get img src from this: $row['DESCRIZIONE']",
     'fonte' => $row['FONTE']
);}
```

Is it possible?
I try with `preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$row['DESCRIZIONE'],$res[0])` but get only 1 as result!

OK I SOLVE SO:

Create a function:

```
function srcImg($num) {
            preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@',$num,$match);
            $src = array_pop($match);
            return $src;
         }
```

and then:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = array(
     'id' => $row['ID_CONTENT'],
     'titolo' => $row['TITOLO'],
     'articolo' => $row['DESCRIZIONE'],
     'giorno' => $row['GIORNO'],
     'foto' => srcImg($row['DESCRIZIONE']),
     'fonte' => $row['FONTE']
);}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: [seems good](https://3v4l.org/pmOTG) to me. how did you use `$res[0]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: It's not a duplicate! I use $row array to trasform results in json string. So I need to get directly foto = src image

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend what @Javier Núñez suggest, and use an HTML Parser as regex just cannot cover all the eventualities for this. However if for any reason you can't, then you could try using this regex: (untested)

```
src=['"]([^"]+)['"]
```

and you can use that in a preg_match as follows:

```
preg_match( '@src=['"]([^"]+)['"]@', $row['DESCRIZIONE'], $match);
$src = array_pop($match);
```

You can tinker with that if you need a hacky approach. We all understand the urgency to get something working over a more perfect solution. ;)

You can use http://regexr.com/ to test your regex if you want to try and make this more robust.

EDIT: I didn't use *preg_match_all*. You'll likely want to use that instead.

Comment: I dont need an array result, because I need only one and than trasform into json!