# How to replace html tags with other tags stored in a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following html code stored in a php variable:

```
<p>This is a sample paragraph</p>
   <img src="img/1.jpg">
<h1>This is my header</h1>
   <img src="img/2.jpg">
<p>I hope someone can help me</p>
   <img src="img/3.jpg">
```

And I have a php array which has three elements, exactly as many as the image elements in the html string:

```
Array(3){
         [0]<img src="img/new1.jpg">
         [1]<img src="img/new2.jpg">
         [2]<img src="img/new3.jpg">
}
```

I'm trying to write a function which will replace the first img tag in the html string with the first array element, the second one with the second in the array and the third with the third in the array.
So that at the end I get this:

```
<p>This is a sample paragraph</p>
    <img src="img/new1.jpg">
    <h1>This is my header</h1>
   <img src="img/new2.jpg">
    <p>I hope someone can help me</p>
    <img src="img/new3.jpg">
```

Believe me I've no idea how to do this. If I would have an idea I would try but the problem is that I can't come to any logic for solving this problem.
Any help would be really great.

Comment: You can change array new elements?

Comment: The number of images is constantly 3 or is it changing?

Comment: @GyulaSoós the number of the image tags in the html string will be always equal to the number of the image tags in the array.

Comment: Split (explode in php), trim, indexOf img, replace, use counter for correct array index.

Comment: @Naumov Sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: Try a loop with `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()`

Comment: You need parse html dom after compile dom.

Comment: What I don't understand in this question, is *when* you need this to happen. Is the page already rendered and then you want to replace it, or do you want to echo the elements with data from the PHP array while the page is still loading?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php

Comment: @Xorifelse I want to replace the tags and save it into the database. When rendering the page, the data will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: @avip You can't pass a string to the pattern parameter of the preg_replace and pass an array to the second parameter. Do you know a way to solve this?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I already looked at that page. But It's not replacing anything but it's just extracting image tags and attributes. I don't need to retrieve the image tags or the attributes but just want to find them and replace each one with it's corresponding one in the array.

Comment: @DevMan you'd have to loop through them one by one. Quick question, in your array, are you able to have just the image path rather than the entire tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to have your new image tag array hold only the path/file info rather than entirely new HTML tags then something similar to the following should work:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<p>This is a sample paragraph</p>
   <img src="img/1.jpg">
<h1>This is my header</h1>
   <img src="img/2.jpg">
<p>I hope someone can help me</p>
   <img src="img/3.jpg">
HTML;

$newImages = ['img/new1.jpg', 'img/new2.jpg', 'img/new3.jpg'];

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

for ($i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++)
    $images->item($i)->setAttribute('src', $newImages[$i]);

// Your updated HTML is now in $html    
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Note**: You can modify your new image array to have only path/image using `preg_replace` or `str_replace`.

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR REPLY AND REQUEST FOR IMPROVEMENT IN ANSWER BELOW:**

- I forgot this with my earlier reply but as of PHP 5.4 and Libxml 2.6, `loadHTML()` accepts Libxml parameters. You can drop all the `str_replace()` stuff (see code).
- There's no need to copy your argument into a local variable if `$content` is a simple string, as it'll be passed by value anyway (the original won't be modified).
- I would not supress errors using `@`, use [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) and [libxml_get_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) instead, in this instance.
- As I mentioned in my comment, I don't see `$imagetag_arr` being passed to the function, declared global, or in front of `$this`. I've added it to the arg list of the function with a more descriptive name.

Updated code:

```
function replaceTags($content, $newImages)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++)
    {
        $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
        $dom2->loadHTML($newImages[$i]);

        $newImg = $dom2->getElementsByTagName('img')
                       ->item(0);

        $images->item($i)->setAttribute('src', $newImg->getAttribute('src'));
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$a=Array (
    'img/1.jpg'=>'img/new1.jpg',
    'img/2.jpg'=>'img/new2.jpg',
    'img/3.jpg'=>'img/new3.jpg');
$replace=array_values($a);
$find=array_keys($a);
$html=str_replace($find, $replace, $html);
```

If you want to replace at a higher level in the HTML object tree, you'll need to use a Dom parser, or run into problems with the likes of:

```
<img
    src='img/1.jpg'
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$source = <<<'EOD'
<p>This is a sample paragraph</p>
   <img src="img/1.jpg">
<h1>This is my header</h1>
   <img src="img/2.jpg">
<p>I hope someone can help me</p>
   <img src="img/3.jpg">
EOD;
$new = [
  '<img src="img/new1.jpg">',
  '<img src="img/new2.jpg">',
  '<img src="img/new3.jpg">',
];
$i = 0;
$result = preg_replace_callback(
  '/<img src="img\/[^.]+\.jpg">/',
  function($matches) use ($new, &$i) {
    return $new[$i++];
  },
  $source
);
```

It's tested and it works.
But maybe somebody could find a more elegant way of using `$new` and `$i`?

Comment: This code works with one exception. All image tags are replaced by the first array element. $new[$i++] seems not to work.

Comment: @DevMan Oh... sorry. As I said, it was tested, but I was focused on checking "new", so I didn't pay attention to the numbers! I edited my answer and now sure it works.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all for your answers. I've some-kind combined all the answers and came to the following solution. It's not the best one from coding perspective and I really feel bad about myself because of writing this "amateur" script. But it's working under all conditions. If someone can improve this code I would be very thankful.

$content is my html string.
$imagetag_arr is the array with the new image tags.

```
 function replaceTags($content){
         $html = $content; //content is my html string.


        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++) {
            $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom2->loadHTML($imagetag_arr[$i]);
            $search = $dom2->getElementsByTagName('img');
            foreach ($search as $item) {
                $newsrc=$item->getAttribute('src');
            }
            $images->item($i)->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);
        }
    // my updated HTML is now in $html

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();


        //because I've saved it as html now the dom object is appending all the html
        //and body tags to my  $final result so I've replaced
       // them all with empty strings.I hate myself
      // for doing it like this.
        $finalhtml=preg_replace('/<![^>]+>/i','',$html);
        $finalhtml=str_replace('<html>','',$finalhtml);
        $finalhtml=str_replace('<body>','',$finalhtml);
        $finalhtml=str_replace('</body>','',$finalhtml);
        $finalhtml=str_replace('</html>','',$finalhtml);

        return $finalhtml;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @avip Sorry my bad. $imagetag_arr is the array, filled with the new image tags. I don't know why someone down-voted my answer. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't see `$imagetag_arr` being passed to the function, declared global, or in front of `$this`, so that function won't work. I didn't downvote it so I've no idea what the reasoning for that was.

Comment: I've updated my original answer with some suggested improvements as you've asked