# Extract text from link

Tags: php

I'd like to extract `onclick="printcoupon('292')"` from this:

```
 [url=http://stackoverflow.com?foo=bar|onclick=printcoupon('292')]foobarbaz[/url]
```

**The text inside the onclick can change dynamically but what I was thinking of was detecting if there is a word onclick inside this and if so grab the contents inside the double quotes (currently it says `printcoupon('292')` )**

Basically though i need to grab either `onclick=printcoupon('292')` or just `printcoupon('292')`.

Either way, this is unfamiliar territory.

```
    function bbcode($str) {
      // situation when str = [url=http://stackoverflow.com?foo=bar|onclick=printcoupon('292')]foobarbaz[/url]
      if(stristr($str,'onclick')){
        $parts=explode('|',$str);
        var_dump($parts);die();
        $str=preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699" onclick="PUT ONCLICK EXTRACTED CONTENT HERE">\2</a>', $str);

      // situation when str = [url=http://stackoverflow.com?foo=bar]foobarbaz[/url]
      } else {
        $str=preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>', $str);
      }
      return $str;
    }
```

So as you can see,

Comment: What is used to output the HTML code in the first place? When you output it can you not just do whatever you need to do with the value then?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Close. I can either grab `onclick=printcoupon('292')` or just `printcoupon('292')`. Not > though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez My question was incorrect. Please see now

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez K

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Code up. Yeh I'm looking at that now but did you see my code updates? I'm not actually using vanilla html and I wouldn't know im only able to scan for onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the substring you want **ALWAYS** begins with "onclick=" and **ALWAYS** ends with ")]", you can do this :

```
<?php
$s = "[url=http://stackoverflow.com?foo=bar|onclick=printcoupon('292')]foobarbaz[/url]";
$onclick = strpos( $s,"onclick=" ); // POSITION OF "ONCLICK=".
$closed_parenthesis = strpos( $s,")]" ); // POSITION OF ")]".
echo substr( $s,$onclick,$closed_parenthesis - $onclick + 1 );
?>
```