# Get HTML Table option value through PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a table option value, specifically the value of "number-per-page" below.

```
<table class="centerTable" number-per-page="3" current-page="0">
```

I need to get the number-per-page option value using php.  Is this possible?  I am using in-line php if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937682/6679116) to a similar question, you can use:

```
$str   = <table class='centerTable' number-per-page='3' current-page="0">
$doc   = new DOMDocument();
$d     = $doc->loadHtml($str);
$tbl   = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');    # select table
$attr  = $tbl->getAttribute('number-per-page');  # get attribute value
```

Alternately, if you add an `id` to your table, you can also use this to select it:

```
$tbl   = $doc->getElementById('your-table-id');
```

For more information, refer [PHP DOM documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

You may try `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('/<table.[^>]*number-per-page="(\d+)".[^>]*>/im', $html, $match);
$number_per_page = $match[1];
```

You may also try a HTML parser for php, there are some libraries out the internet.