# Find and Transform image tags in a block of text

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to use PHP to find all IMG tags within a block of text `$content` and replace them with liquid template tags, while retaining their placement within the text and the `src` and `alt` text for each one.

**Example `$content`**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

<img src="http://example.com/frog.jpg" alt="frog desc" />

Nunc feugiat lorem tellus, et sollicitudin eros feugiat vitae. Aliquam auctor velit nec auctor semper

<img src="http://example.com/snake.jpg" alt="snake desc" />

Donec egestas felis id turpis sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Ut massa arcu, condimentum vitae laoreet auctor, blandit sit amet enim.

<img src="http://example.com/toad.jpg" alt="toad desc" />

<img src="http://example.com/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard desc" />

Maecenas vel purus nec mauris dignissim pellentesque.
```

**Transformed text:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

{% img="frog.jpg" alt="frog desc" %}

Nunc feugiat lorem tellus, et sollicitudin eros feugiat vitae. Aliquam auctor velit nec auctor semper

{% img="snake.jpg" alt="snake desc" %}

Donec egestas felis id turpis sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Ut massa arcu, condimentum vitae laoreet auctor, blandit sit amet enim.

{% img="toad.jpg" alt="toad desc" %}

{% img="lizard.jpg" alt="lizard desc" %}
```

So far, I went down one path of extracting all the images and their attributes into an array using: [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php) but found it was hard to re-insert the images back into the text at their original location.

Any advice would be appreciated :)

PS — Here is the image string I am trying to affect:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/IMG_0061-300x225.jpg" alt="garden image" width="300" height="225" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-386916" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this will be helpful.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/E7TRsg/3)

**Regex:** `<img.*?src=".*\/(?!>)([^"]+)"\s+alt="([^"]+)"[^>]+>`

> **1.** `<img.*?src="` This will match `<img` , then all till `src="`
>
> **2.** `.*\/(?!>)` this will match all till `/` there next character is not `>`
>
> **3.** `([^"]+)` This will match all till except `"` and `()` will capture this in first group.
>
> **4.** `"\s+alt="` this will match `"` then some `spaces` then `alt="`
>
> **5.** `([^"]+)"` this will match all except `"` then match `"` then `()` will capture this in second group.
>
> **6.** `[^>]+>` this will match except `>` and then match this `>`

**Replacement:** `{% img="$1" alt="$2" %}`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/806445)

```
<?php

$string=<<<HTML
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

<img src="http://example.com/frog.jpg" alt="frog" />

Nunc feugiat lorem tellus, et sollicitudin eros feugiat vitae. Aliquam auctor velit nec auctor semper

<img src="http://example.com/snake.jpg" alt="snake" />

Donec egestas felis id turpis sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Ut massa arcu, condimentum vitae laoreet auctor, blandit sit amet enim.

<img src="http://example.com/toad.jpg" alt="toad" />

<img src="http://example.com/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" />

Maecenas vel purus nec mauris dignissim pellentesque. 
HTML;
echo preg_replace('/<img.*?src=".*\/(?!>)([^"]+)"\s+alt="([^"]+)"[^>]+>/', '{% img="$1" alt="$2" %}', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you Sahil — I will give this a try

Comment: That first DEMO you posted is perfect — Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While Sahil's pattern does return the desired effect, it is not as efficient as it could/should be.  It makes too many capture groups, and takes 60% more steps than my pattern.

Use this pattern instead: `/<img src="[^"]*\/([^"]+" alt="[^"]+") \/>/`
([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8w0sdm/1))

Implementation ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ad14de3c22e2b114ce3939503dbbd8d2cba8f79)):

```
$content='
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

<img src="http://example.com/frog.jpg" alt="frog" />

Nunc feugiat lorem tellus, et sollicitudin eros feugiat vitae. Aliquam auctor velit nec auctor semper

<img src="http://example.com/snake.jpg" alt="snake" />

Donec egestas felis id turpis sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Ut massa arcu, condimentum vitae laoreet auctor, blandit sit amet enim.

<img src="http://example.com/toad.jpg" alt="toad" />

<img src="http://example.com/lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" />

Maecenas vel purus nec mauris dignissim pellentesque.';
echo preg_replace('/<img src="[^"]*\/([^"]+" alt="[^"]+") \/>/', '{% img="$1 %}', $content);
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

{% img="frog.jpg" alt="frog" %}

Nunc feugiat lorem tellus, et sollicitudin eros feugiat vitae. Aliquam auctor velit nec auctor semper

{% img="snake.jpg" alt="snake" %}

Donec egestas felis id turpis sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Ut massa arcu, condimentum vitae laoreet auctor, blandit sit amet enim.

{% img="toad.jpg" alt="toad" %}

{% img="lizard.jpg" alt="lizard" %}

Maecenas vel purus nec mauris dignissim pellentesque.
```